# /deterministic switch for msbuild does not work

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2015, msbuild

I want to try the /deterministic switch from VS 2015 Update 2.
I have VS 2015 Update 3, but when try to use this switch like:

"msbuild  /deterministic"

I get:
MSBUILD : error MSB1001: Unknown switch.
Switch: /deterministic

What am I missing here?

Comment: It is a compiler option, not an msbuild option.  Type `msbuild /?` to see what options are acceptable.  Compare to `csc /?`. Use the /p argument to set properties.  But surely you ought to favor adding  `<Deterministic>true</Deterministic>` to your project file.  Keeps it deterministic :)

Comment: Thanks Hans, adding <Deterministic>true</Deterministic> worked

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently as Hans Passant pointed out, this is a compiler option and not of MSBuild.exe.

After adding the true to my csproj files, I was able to build deterministically.
Thanks!

Comment: Where exactly do you add this within the csproj?

Comment: under the first <propertyGroup> element

Answer (score 12):

To expand on Hans' comment-answer, `deterministic` is a compiler-specific option that MSBuild has no knowledge of. To get MSBuild to pass this option through to the compiler, you can do one of two things.

- Edit your .csproj file to define the variable `Deterministic` in the first `PropertyGroup`:

```
    <Project ...>
      <PropertyGroup>
        ...
        <Deterministic>True/False</Deterministic>
        ...
      </PropertyGroup>

      ...
    </Project>
```

- Use the [`property` switch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-za/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-command-line-reference#switches) on the command-line:

`> msbuild /property:Deterministic=True/False MyProject.csproj`

Reference: [blog of Jared Parsons](https://blog.paranoidcoding.com/2016/04/05/deterministic-builds-in-roslyn.html), the C# Compiler Team Developer Lead (until Microsoft properly documents this).

Comment: Many thanks for the reference citation. I have read and derived benefit from the work of its author, Jared Parsons, for a number of years. I think it's safe to call his writing on this subject authoritative.